# Eclipse Android two buttons

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Please help me! I want to make a bus timetable application, but I can't make this activity with two buttons. It says that "Duplicate method addListenerOnButton() in type _tiz_oda".
Activity layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="._tiz_oda" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_10_oda"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/text_10_1"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_10_10_oda"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/button_10"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_10_ora_oda"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button_10_oda"
    android:text="@string/text_ora" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_10_ures_oda"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_10_munkanap_oda"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView_10_munkanap_oda"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="@string/text_ures" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_10_szabad_oda"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button_10_oda"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView_10_munkanap_oda"
    android:text="@string/text_szabad" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView_10_oda"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView_10_szabad_oda"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:numColumns="3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_10_megallok_oda"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_10_oda"
    android:text="@string/text_megallok" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_10_oda"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView_10_irany_oda"
    android:text="@string/text_10_3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_10_irany_oda"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button_10_oda"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView_10_oda"
    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
    android:text="@string/text_irany" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_10_munkanap_oda"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView_10_ora_oda"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView_10_ora_oda"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_10_oda"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:text="@string/text_munkanap" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And activity .java:

```
package com.szfvar.buszmenetrend;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class _tiz_oda extends Activity {

Button button;

GridView gridView_10;

static final String[] numbers = new String[] { 
        "4", "35,50", "35",
        "5", "00,20,50", "20",
        "6", "25,50", "25",
        "7", "20", "20",
        "8", "20", "20",
        "9", "20", "20",
        "10", "20", "20",
        "11", "20", "20",
        "12", "20,45", "20",
        "13", "20,50", "20",
        "14", "20,50", "25",
        "15", "20,50", "20",
        "16", "20,50", "20",
        "17", "20,50", "20",
        "18", "20", "20",
        "19", "00,25", "25",
        "20", "25", "25",
        "21", "20", "20",
        "22", "35", "35",};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tiz_oda);

    gridView_10 = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView_10_oda);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers);

    gridView_10.setAdapter(adapter);

    gridView_10.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            ((TextView) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    addListenerOnButton();
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_10_oda);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, _tiz_vissza.class);
            startActivity(intent);   

        }

    });
    addListenerOnButton();
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_10_megallok_oda);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, _tiz_megallok_oda.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });


}

}
```

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared this method, `public void addListenerOnButton() {` twice.

You can't do that. Otherwise, when you call it, how would the compiler know which one to use?

Instead:

```
public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_10_oda);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, _tiz_vissza.class);
            startActivity(intent);   

    }

    otherButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_10_megallok_oda);

    otherButton .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, _tiz_megallok_oda.class);
            startActivity(intent);

       }
});
```

}

Of course, you should use better names than `button` and `otherButton` like `10_oda` and `10_megallok_oda`.